# Empty array when passed to response()->json

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a method in parent class

Controller.php

```
public function invalidError($errors = [], $code = 422)
{
    return response()->json([
        'errors' => $errors
    ], $code);
}
```

I am passing this method the following:

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->invalidError([
        array('key' => 'Some key')
    ]);
}
```

When the response comes in the `errors` message is always empty array like the following:

```
{
    "errors": []
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To get the errors array from a validator, use `failed()`

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->invalidError($validator->failed());
}
```

If you wants the messages from the failed rules use `messages()`

```
if($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->invalidError($validator->messages());
}
```

For more information, you can check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#basic-usage)

Comment: Still returns empty array in the response.

Comment: Just to mention that the parent class is extended in the following manner:
`Parent -> Child -> Sub-child`, and `Sub-Child` is calling the Parent's method `invalidError`

Comment: @Gammer maybe you did override the parent method in one of those child/sub-child. because in your sample example, you should have received the static result.

Comment: I have just checked again, there is no such method even in the entire codebase.